# Wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
def self.grab

    article = self.article_names
    links = self.article_links
    body = self.article_body


    articles = {}
    articles[:title] = article
    articles[:url] = links
    articles[:body] = body

    art = Ello::Hello.new

    art(articles)

end
```

When I run this with

```
class Ello::Hello
attr_accessor :url, :article, :body,

@@all = []

def initialize(hash)
    @article = hash["title"]
    @body = hash["body"]
    @url = hash["url"]
    @@all << self
   end

def self.all
    @@all
  end
 end
```

I get wrong number of arguments error? I know that usually when it says wrong number it means that it's not exactly reading the argument that I put in. But I feel like I did put in an argument but I'm unsure of why it's not being read.

Comment: Use `Ello::Hello.new(articles)` instead, the parameters must be passed right when you initialize a new object.

Comment: The error message tells you what line the error occurs on.

Comment: Seeing a class variable here is usually a sign things have gone awry. Consider using a different approach, like where `self.all` is defined as `@all ||= [ ]` and then you can do `self.class.all << self` in the instance *if* you need this. Remember retaining every object can prevent the garbage collector from doing its job.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, you should always paste the complete error message, and indicate which line in your code is affected.

Anyway, I can see that your wrote `art = Ello::Hello.new` (0 arguments), but the `initialize` method for this class expects 1 argument.